# play a sound file through the audioflinger using native android code

Tags: android, audio, audioflinger

This is exactly what I want . I want to know how to write a C code that will be able to directly access the audio-flinger in the android. ofcourse the audio-flinger would be exporting some Interface. I think there could be a libaudio.so that I ll include in my compile and then call a simple play function that implements this. just give something like play("filename");Any idea.

Cheers
Vaishali